# find(Class,id) and JPQL get different object (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using Hibernate 4.1.10.Final as my JPA provider, Spring and Spring MVC. There are two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_a_id")
    private A a;
}
```

I need to get an `A` and it's `b`s, so I use the `find(A.class,id)` of EntityManager.

```
A a1 = em.find(A.class, id);
a1.getBs().size();
```

For which the result is: the size of `b`s is zero (which means that there is no associated B). 
But I'm sure that there are many associated Bs in the database, and indeed the data can been loaded from database while checking via the console.

When I use Query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A AS a WHERE a.id = ?1",A.class);
query.setParameter(1, id);
A a= (A) query.getSingleResult();
a.getBs().size(); // = 22
```

I instead get a size = 22.

What's wrong?

Comment: set hibernate *show_sql* property and watch what difference is there in the executed sql queries.

Comment: I have compare two executed sqls, and the sqls using Query is just a select clause and resolving associations, but the find() have some steps to do that. Frist, it load the A and then load associated entities. But bs have not be associated with A.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the `mappedBy` property in your `@OneToMany`, the owner of the relation is B and not A. That's why when you load an instance of A, the corresponding Bs are not loaded. Try modifying your annotations with the following :

In class A :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="fk_a_id")
private Set<B> bs;
```

In class B :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_a_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private A a;
```

Comment: I check this way, but didn't get the right bs. Its size is zero.

Comment: So i prefer the JPQL but not find()